# Template not showing correct calculated values

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to display the total amount that each user would get in a table on my template.  Now when I do print statements in my console, I get the correct values but then when I put `{{ total_dollar_amount }}` on my template, it only shows me the last value.

Now I thought that I should loop through `total_dollar_amount` but then it throws an error saying decimal value isn't iterable.

Anyone know what I am missing?

views.py

```
def ABD_report(request, *args, **kwargs):
"""
This report will show all 'In Trust For' investments in the system and display all relevant information
"""
from investments.models import Investment
from reports.forms import InTrustForm
context = {}
if request.POST:
    form = InTrustForm(request.agents, request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        agents = form.cleaned_data['agents']
        context['selected_agents'] = agents
        investments = Investment.objects.filter(plan__profile__agent__in=agents, plan__ownership_type__code = "itf")
        for i in investments:
            #count all members in each plan
            count = i.plan.planmember_set.all().count()
            #take off the primary member of the account
            count -= 1
            if i.interestoption:
                if i.interestoption.short_label == 'AN':
                    pay_amt = i.pay_amount
                    total_amt = (pay_amt / count)
                    context['total_dollar_amt'] = total_amt
            context['counted'] = count
        context['investments'] = investments
        context['show_report'] = True
else:
    form = InTrustForm(request.agents)

context['form'] = form

return render_to_response('reports/admin/abd_report.html', RequestContext(request, context))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `context` variable is a dictionary; each key can only have one value. You're looping through `investments` and setting the same two keys, `context['total_dollar_amt']` and `context['counted']`, on each loop - so on each iteration you overwrite the previous value.

If you want to be able to loop through the `counted` and `total_dollar_amt` values for each investment, you need to attach this to the investment object, not set a key in `context`:

```
for i in investments:
    #count all members in each plan
    count = i.plan.planmember_set.all().count()
    #take off the primary member of the account
    count -= 1
    if i.interestoption:
        if i.interestoption.short_label == 'AN':
            pay_amt = i.pay_amount
            total_amt = (pay_amt / count)
            # attach value to the investment
            i.total_dollar_amt = total_amt
    # attach value to the investment
    i.counted = count
```

Now in your template, you can loop through `investments`.

Answer (score 1):

`context['total_dollar_amt']` is getting overwritten every time the assignment gets hit in the loop. To see the value that will be passed to the template, do `print context['total_dollar_amt']` just before `render_to_response`.

It's not totally clear to me from your description, but I think you need to be passing a list of dicts to context instead - like `context['investments_data'] = []`, then in the loop, `context['investments_data'].append({'inv': i, 'total_dollar_amt': total_amt})`, or similar. Then in the template:

```
{% for inv_data in investments_data %}
    {{ inv_data.inv.name }} total: {{ inv_data.total_amt }}
{% endfor %}
```